# Magento 2 . How to hide 'Add to cart' button while not logged in

Tags: magento2, module, addtocart, plugin

This is how I tried but its not working
`Bodak/DisableAddToCart/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="catalog">
            <group id="frontend">
                <field id="catalog_frontend_disable_add_to_cart_for_guest" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="250" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Disable Add to cart button for Guests</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then in `Bodak/DisableAddToCart/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Bodak_IsSalablePlugin::after" type="Bodak\DisableAddToCart\Plugin\IsSalablePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then after that `Bodak/DisableAddToCart/Plugin/IsSalablePlugin.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Bodak\DisableAddToCart\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Class IsSalablePlugin
 *
 * @category Plugin
 * @package  Bodak\DisableAddToCart\Plugin
 */
class IsSalablePlugin
{
    /**
     * Scope config
     *
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * HTTP Context
     * Customer session is not initialized yet
     *
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;

    const DISABLE_ADD_TO_CART = 'catalog/frontend/catalog_frontend_disable_add_to_cart_for_guest';

    /**
     * SalablePlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Context              $context     Context
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * Check if is disable add to cart and if customer is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsSalable(): bool
    {
        $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::DISABLE_ADD_TO_CART, $scope)) {
            if ($this->context->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Have you tried https://magenticians.com/hide-add-to-cart-guest-users-magento-2/?

Use `Observer` instead of `plugin` please refer above link.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Its not working nor giving me any error...

Comment: @ChiragPatel yeah buddy I tried that one but this only hide the 'Add to cart' from specific place not from everywhere...

Answer (score 2):

**Follow below steps to hide Add to Cart button for Guest user.**

> File path: magento/app/code/Guest/AddtoCartHideGuest/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Guest_AddtoCartHideGuest',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Guest/AddtoCartHideGuest/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Guest_AddtoCartHideGuest" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Guest/AddtoCartHideGuest/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Guest_IsSalablePlugin::after" type="Guest\AddtoCartHideGuest\Plugin\IsSalablePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Guest/AddtoCartHideGuest/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="guest" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
            <label>Guest Add to Cart</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="guest_addtocart" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Add to Cart for Guest</label>
            <tab>guest</tab>
            <resource>Guest_AddtoCartHideGuest::system_config</resource>
            <group id="guest" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Disable Add to Cart Button For Guest</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
             </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Go to admin and set **Disable Add to Cart Button For Guest** >> **Enable: Yes**

**Admin path: Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> GUEST ADD TO CART >> Add to Cart for Guest >> Disable Add to Cart Button For Guest >> Enable: Yes**

Let in know if any issue.

Hope it help!

Comment: Just got the original repo https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-b2b-disable-add-to-cart-button-for-guest

Answer (score 0):

> **Hide Add To Cart**

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidecartbutton" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\Hidecartbutton" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin**

**Hidecartbutton.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Vendorename\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Hidecartbutton
{
    protected $_customerSessionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
    }
    public function afterIsSaleable(Product $product, $isSaleable)
    {
        // check customer login or not
        $cust_data = $this->_customerSessionFactory->create();
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $product->isSalable();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***