# Is there a way to disable "add to cart" and "wishlist" for customers that aren't logged in

Tags: login, magento2.2.4

Like the title says, those buttons look terrible when customers aren't logged in, and the functionality ins't needed, so how can I disable favorites and compare for people who aren't logged in?

Thanks

Comment: For hide add to cart click here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324997/82670

Answer (score 1):

We can disable Add to cart and Wishlist for Not Logged in User by "layout_generate_blocks_after" event

Create these files in a custom module.

> etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
    <observer name="update_layout" instance="Bytepattern\RemoveBlock\Observer\UpdateLayout" />
</event>
</config>
```

> Observer/UpdateLayout.php

```
<?php

namespace Bytepattern\RemoveBlock\Observer;

class UpdateLayout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

private $httpContext;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
) {
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

/**
 * Execute observer.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $layout = $observer->getLayout();

    if(!$this->isLoggedIn()) {
        // Customer is not logged in
        $layout->unsetElement('product.info.addtocart');
        $layout->unsetElement('wish-list-link');
        $layout->unsetElement('minicart');
        
     } 

    return $this;
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    return $isLoggedIn;
}
}
```

> Note: Replace Bytepattern/RemoveBlock with your Vendor/Module

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no way to disable wishlist and add to the cart for only not-logged in customers. You can only disable totally wishlist

In my case, I was already been struggled to disable add to cart for not logged in but finally, came up with some additional extensions.